# Why controllers?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller, sinatra

I have spent alot of time developing on sinatra, and that has worked fine for me because I have only worked on small projects and scale has not been a problem. Now I have the need to use rails, and the structure is a little confusing to me. I understand that when I type `localhost:3000/images` rails looks for the route in `routes.rb` (e.g. `get 'images#index'`), then goes the the controller `images` then in images looks for a `index` function, and finally finds the `index` view and renders it.

Why are all of these changes necessary? Couldn't it be simpler like sinatra (which seems to just include the controller step in the main file)? In an answer I am looking for why it is better to do it the way rails does it including specific reasons, advantages and disadvantage with examples.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can the downvoters please explain so I can improve my question?

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I did flag as primarily opinion-based, because I believe it is. Its an opinion as to why controllers are good to have, just like its an opinion as to whether to use Rails or Sinatra. Those sorts of questions are considered out of the scope of SO, since they're much better suited to a forum-like discussion environment than to a Q-A one like this.

Comment: I am trying not to ask which is better, but why rails uses controllers.

Comment: The simple answer is that it follows the MVC paradigm and that has controllers by design. This is why Rails has controllers. If you question why MVC has controllers then you are basically questioning the MVC pattern, which is a matter of opinion.

Comment: Ok thank you! This actually answers my question very well.

Comment: Should I delete my question then?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Konstantin Haase](http://rkh.im/) is the current maintainer of Sinatra and feels that they both cater for different types of application:

> They are both solving a different set of issues, even though they
>   indeed overlap. While Rails is a framework focused on writing model
>   driven web applications, Sinatra is a library for dealing with HTTP
>   from the server side. If you think in terms of HTTP
>   requests/responses, Sinatra is the ideal tool. If you need full
>   integration and as much boilerplate as possible, Rails is the way to
>   go.

[David Heinemeier Hansson](http://david.heinemeierhansson.com/) also believes that there was room for both of them, but feels that is size of your app that should influence which one to use:

> Sinatra is great for the micro-style, Rails is not. As long as you
>   stay micro, Sinatra will beat Rails. If you go beyond micro, Rails
>   will beat Sinatra.

So, basically, Sinatra and Rails are different and they have different use cases. Rails is an open source full-stack web application framework. It follows the popular **MVC framework (Model, View, Controller)** model and is known for its "**convention over configuration**" approach to application development. So, as you can see `controller` is a part of Rails by design.

You can find many articles describing the differences between Rails and Sinatra and their use cases. Here are couple of interesting blogs:

[Rails vs. Sinatra](https://blog.engineyard.com/2014/rails-vs-sinatra)

[Rails vs. Sinatra by Example](https://www.airpair.com/ruby-on-rails/posts/rails-vs-sinatra)

Answer (score 3):

K M Rakibul Islam's answer is great. You might also check out [Rack](http://rack.github.io). Both Rails and Sinatra are built on it. Rack is a web server interface that expects an "app" to be a Ruby object that takes a request hash via a method called `call` and then to respond with an array that includes the http response code, the http headers and the response body. It's pretty barebones. Looking at Rack might give you a better sense of how the two diverge past that-- if you're interested in "how" rather than "why".